# insert_or_assign is allowing iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17, const-iterator

I have this piece of code:

```
auto it = my_map.lower_bound(my_key);
```

The following assert gives me error:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(it), std::map<K, V>::const_iterator>::value, "Error");
```

And the following one, is ok:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(it), std::map<K, V>::iterator>::value, "Error");
```

Then, the compiler is not giving me a `const_iterator`. Ok. But here:

```
my_map.insert_or_assign(it, my_key, some_val);
```

even with `iterator` (not `const_iterator`), the function is working. But, in this [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign), on `insert_or_assign` signatures, I only have `const_iterator` arguments. I also searched for the `.h` file on Visual Studio and this information matches. Tested on GCC 7.2+  and Visual Studio 2015, everything compiles and runs.

Why does it compile? Why `insert_or_assign` accepts `iterator`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All containers are required to provide an `iterator` type that is convertible to `const_iterator`. See the [*Container requirements*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/container.requirements.general#tab:containers.container.requirements) table

`X​::​iterator` is required to be *any iterator category that meets the forward iterator requirements. **convertible to `X::const_iterator`**.*

So a `const_iterator` is being constructed from the `iterator` returned by `lower_bound` in the call to `insert_or_assign`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `lower_bound` call will give you a non-const iterator on non-const map. However, there is an automatic conversion from non-const iterator to const-iterator, so any function which requires const_iterator can be called with non-const iterator of the same type.