# New std::map::erase() signature C++17

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, c++17, const-iterator

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50726388/1455108), an `iterator` must be implicitly convertible to `const_iterator`. Since that is true, as we can see happening in [`insert_or_assign()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign), then why in C++17 was a new signature added to [`std::map::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase)?

In C++11, we have `iterator erase( const_iterator pos );`

In C++17, we now have `iterator erase( iterator pos );`

Wasn't the C++11 signature good enough to receive `iterator` and `const_iterator`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's a potential ambiguity with `erase(const key_type& key)` when you pass an `iterator`. Consider the case where the `key_type` is something like `std::any`.